# Is a batsman out if his broken bat is caught?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a batsman's bat breaks while he is hitting a shot and a fielder catches the broken bat - not the ball - is the batsman out?

Comment: What makes you believe the batsman might possibly be out?

Answer (score 5):

No, the laws of cricket (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caught) clearly state that a batsman can only be out caught if the fielder catches the ball fully within the field of play without it bouncing after touching the batsman's bat or glove.

There are other modes of dismissal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_cricket#Ways_to_get_out) none of which involve the fielder catching the batsman's bat (broken or otherwise).